# jQuery animation divide page in half and reveal a div

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, slideup

I have a grid layout on my page displaying photos inside li's would like some help animating it on click of an item to display content inside a hidden div that will be revealed.
I would like:

```
a. raise half of the page(and its contents)
b. increase the size of a div in the center for ajax content to be loaded.
c. lower the lower half of the page(and its contents)
```

code pen (test): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yktvD

Comment: Without any sketch I can not understand an animation concept. Try http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/

Comment: this is exactly what i want but i dnt want to go through the integration proccess because this animation relies on stacked divs
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/

Comment: What does "raise half of the page" mean?  What does "lower the lower half of the page" mean?

Comment: take a look at the example on the codrops website - tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider this is the effect im trying to mimic

Comment: I know you are waiting a piece of magical code, but might be better download a entire page by the link if it so desirable and amaze you? This page is precisely sequenced css animation. Recreate it from scratch -- hours of job. I not sure there somewhere exist "the library" of exactly same animations like this. I'm really sorry!

Answer (score 1):

> a. raise half of the page(and its contents)

When a button is clicked, I will assume that all this animation will execute when the click is made on a button! So

```
.element {
  margin: 0; // on load no margins..
}

$('button').click(function () { // start the jquery animation..
  $('.element').css({ // alter the css properties..
      margin: '0 0 50% 0' // change the margin..
  })
}
```

> b. increase the size of a div in the center for ajax content to be loaded.

For this, you will be using this line:

```
$('element').css({
  height: 'addmoreheight',
  /* if more are required! */
})
```

Now do this:

```
$('button').click(function () { // you can change the event..
   /* and at the same time, load the ajax content */
   $('otherelement').load('page_url'); // load the page content in element
   // or this one
   $.ajax({ // start the ajax request; alternate to the load
     url: 'page_url', // url to the page
     success: function (data) { // catch the response on success
       $('otherelement').html(data); // write the response
     }
   })
}
```

This is the example of how you would be able to add the bottom margin to an element, and load ajax data in another element and show it at the bottom!

> c. lower the lower half of the page(and its contents)

Similar thing here, just move it a bit at the bottom! By adding margins, or by using `position: absolute` and giving the parameters!